# Devise - override redirect for the custom login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have the following interesting problem.  I've created a secondary login form.  From that secondary form I want the user always to be redirected to the specific form.  I believe Devise is handling redirects in the following function in **ApplicationController**:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  # custom redirect stuff
end
```

What would be the best way to tell devise *"if I am coming from the custom redirect path, always take me to some specific page and disregard what ever is in params[:redirect]"*.  I was thinking of either inspecting referrer url string or storing stuff on the session, but I am not sure.

What would be the best way to achieve this behaviour? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there any difference in the functionality provided to the users depending on which page they login from? If the difference is significant, then perhaps having different roles and use cancan to authorize access might be a way to go. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863475/using-devise-with-rails-3-adding-multiple-roles for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting Devise code, I found that it is possible by clearing out the session variable where Devise stores the return path:

```
session[:user_return_to] = nil # or some explicit path
```

**Note:** Assuming the authenticated model is **user.rb**