# Wrong URLs in Devise with multiple roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

After defining two roles in Devise and running `rails g devise:views` for each of them, I am having problems with the URL helpers used in the views.

For example, `new_session_path(:client)` returns `/session/new.client` instead of `/clients/session/new`.

At the top of my `routes.rb` I left the two `devise_for` directives untouched, not modifying any of the paths.

Any idea why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try with cancan which provide you a better way to define all the roles, and restriction of all the roles to access each of the controller.

Comment: This has nothing to do with authorization, I'm afraid.

Comment: ohh, actually im just suggesting a method, because you implementing 2 roles for ur devise. So actually you can just having 1 roles which is user instead of 2 ,and manage ur stuff, so you wont have those devise routes problem which have 2 roles. Just a suggestion only @@' :) i vote it up to get more attention. In case, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863475/using-devise-with-rails-3-adding-multiple-roles?rq=1 :) cheers

Comment: The 2 Roles have very different implementations, so they can't be both instances of the same class.

Comment: Well, it's 2 classes, `Client` and `Lawyer`, and they don't share much common code, so they can't both belong to just one class with only an attribute to differentiate them. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think `CanCan` is the answer to my problem.